# Is there a combat log in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm a player that tries to get the most of his character and find crunching/analyzing numbers fun (weird I know).

Is there a combat log that is being generated/recorded in Diablo 3? Or is recording/review my only option at this point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't I've looked high and low, and found nothing. Many forums asking the same question, all answers are no.